# r ggplot barplot with multiple date columns

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have a data frame with multiple date columns and I want to make a single plot with 3 bar charts (one for ID/dat1, ID/dat2 and ID/dat3). Anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: I'm looking for a plot with the date on the x-axis and count of ID on the y-axis.

Example data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = c(1:80),
                     dat1 = sample(seq(as.Date('2021/01/01'), as.Date('2021/04/01'), by="day"), 80),
                     dat2 = sample(seq(as.Date('2021/01/01'), as.Date('2021/04/01'), by="day"), 80),
                     dat3 = sample(seq(as.Date('2021/01/01'), as.Date('2021/04/01'), by="day"), 80))
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you after this?

```
melt(setDT(dat), id.vars = "ID") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

---

If you want to have line plot, you can try

```
melt(setDT(dat),id.vars = "ID") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = ID, group = variable, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a plot with the date on the x-axis and the ID cont on the y-axis. Maybe a line plot would be better since there will be a ot of overlap.

Comment: @Joep_S See my update to check if that's what you want.

Comment: Almost, but it should be overlapping. So just 1 x-axis. That's where my problem is because each date vector has its own values and these should somehow be "merged" to one x-axis

Comment: @Joep_S Okey, I see. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Joep_S I don't know what kind of line plot you want. See my update

Comment: Thanks! the line plot was what I was looking for, but now that I see it, it may not be the most clarifying way of presenting my data. Another remark: The IDs seem to be summed instead of counted (there are only 80 IDs in total). How can I fix that?

Comment: Thanks. It works for the bar plot, but if I use  melt(setDT(dat),id.vars = "ID") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, group = variable, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line() for the line plot I get the error "geom_line requires aesthetics y". When I add y = ID I get the individual values for ID on the y-axis instead of the count. So removing y=ID works for the bar plot, but not the line plot

Comment: @Joep_S `geom_line` needs `y` to position the line coordinates. You shouldn't skip it. which is different from `geom_bar`

Comment: I fixed it by removing y=ID and adding  + geom_line(stat="count")

Comment: @Joep_S Yes, it seems you seems finding a workaround.

Comment: Any idea how I can add a group by to this? Besides ID and the 3 dat variables I have a factor with 4 values and I want to make 4 plots, one for each factor category. Simply adding a group by to the code obviously doesn't work